# How to compute RandomReal faster?

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, syntax, random

I have variables $E_{1},E_{3}$ that are bounded in the following way:
$$
\tag 1 E_{1}>m_{1}, \quad E_{3}>m_{3}, E_{2}\equiv m-E_{1}-E_{3}>m_{2}, \\ -1 < \frac{E_{2}^{2}-m_{2}^{2}-(E_{1}^{2}-m_{1}^{2})-(E_{3}^{2}-m_{3}^{2})}{2\sqrt{E_{1}^{2}-m_{1}^{2}}\sqrt{E_{3}^{2}-m_{3}^{2}}}< 1
$$
Here, $m>m_{1}+m_{2}+m_{3}$, and all $m,m_{1},m_{2},m_{3}$ are positive real numbers.

I would like to generate random values of $E_{1},E_{3}$ that satisfy $(1)$. However, my code is slow. Could you please tell me how to make it faster?

```
(*Generating the domain (1)*)
pPar[En_, mass_] = Sqrt[En^2 - mass^2];
E2[m_, E1_, E3_] = m - E1 - E3;
costheta13[E1_, E3_, m_, m1_, m2_, 
   m3_] = (pPar[E2[m, E1, E3], m2]^2 - pPar[E1, m1]^2 - 
     pPar[E3, m3]^2)/(2*pPar[E1, m1]*pPar[E3, m3]);
E3domain[E1_, m_, m1_, m2_, m3_] = 
 E3 /. Assuming[m > 0 && E1 > m1 > 0, 
   Simplify[Solve[costheta13[E1, E3, m, m1, m2, m3] == 1, E3]]]
E1domain[m_, m1_, m2_, 
  m3_] = {E1 /. 
    Solve[E3domain[E1, m, m1, m2, m3][[1]] - 
        E3domain[E1, m, m1, m2, m3][[2]] == 0, E1][[2]], 
   E1 /. Solve[
      E3domain[E1, m, m1, m2, m3][[1]] - 
        E3domain[E1, m, m1, m2, m3][[2]] == 0, E1][[3]]} // Simplify
(*Generating random reals*)
BlockRandomVectors[m_, m1_, m2_, m3_] := 
 Block[{mass1 = m}, 
  E1rand = RandomReal[{E1domain[m, m1, m2, m3][[1]], 
     E1domain[m, m1, m2, m3][[2]]}];
  E3rand = 
   RandomReal[{E3domain[E1rand, m, m1, m2, m3][[1]], 
     E3domain[E1rand, m, m1, m2, m3][[2]]}];
  {E1rand, E3rand}]
Table[BlockRandomVectors[10, 0.5, 1, 0.2], {i, 1, 10^6, 
    1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {84.4381,Null}

Comment: Do you want $E_1$ and $E_3$ to be distributed uniformly within these constraints?

Comment: Thanks! No, initially I wanted to generate with some weights, but  them decided to simplify the task via separating.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to generate a 4 point kinematical configuration in special relativity? I think it would be easier to generate the momenta and calculate the energies from there, why did you decide to generate the energies?

Comment: @Joe : this is because energies specify all the relevant kinematics.

Comment: Ok sure but there's no harm in generating the momenta even if this includes extra info that you don't need. How many dimensions are you working in? And what does the last inequality refer to physically? It looks like $\frac{|p_4|}{2|p_1||p_3|}\in (-1,1)$, which is strange because the mass dimension doesn't match up

Comment: @Joe : the last inequality is $-1<\cos(\theta_{p_{1},p_{2}})<1$. There is a mistake, the momenta in the numerator must be squared. My task is actually to generate the 3-body distribution in the lab frame of a decaying particle, and for this purpose, it is more convenient for me to express the matrix element of the given process squared in terms of energies, then generate energies from the allowed phase space, and finally reweight events with the matrix element squared.

Comment: I understand that you want to generate arbitrary 3-particle kinematics that obey momentum conservation, but you're only interested in the energies and not the directions of the 3-momenta, is that right? It would be easier to generate random momenta and then calculate the energies from this; after that you can throw away the momenta if you don't need them. If you do it this way you won't have to worry about cosine inequalities because all such relationships will be automatically satisfied and also the code will be faster and less likely to have errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131994/discussion-between-joe-and-john-taylor).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a rejection step, and compilation:

```
r = Compile[{m, m1, m2, m3},
      Module[{E1 = 0., E2 = 0., E3 = 0.},
        While[
          E1 = RandomReal[{m1, m - m3 - m2}];
          E3 = RandomReal[{m3, m - m1 - m2}];
          E2 = m - E1 - E3;
          E2 <= m2 || (Sqrt[E2^2-m2^2]-Sqrt[E1^2-m1^2]-Sqrt[E3^2-m3^2])^2 >= 4*(E1^2-m1^2)*(E3^2-m3^2)];
        {E1, E3}],
      CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];

T = Table[r[10, 0.5, 1, 0.2], 10^6]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*    {0.714959, Null}    *)
```